# From a windows computer to an ubuntu computer

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I bought a laptop with Windows 10 preinstalled. My history is with Ubuntu, and this new Windows is proving to be a wretched OS. How do I get rid of it and load ANY version of Ubuntu?  (14.04 was my favorite, back in the day.) I'm finding linux sites oddly complicated and unhelpful. 
    This Lenovo laptop has no diskette drive, so the only option for loading Ubuntu is a flash drive. Can someone tell me (step-by-step) how to turn this into a linux machine? No dual-boots, please. 
Kent Smith, Merida Mexico

Comment: All you need to know is at https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Very easy to find too.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [these instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to make a bootable usb stick of Ubuntu Live. Here it is summarized:

> 1. Have a 4GB+ USB stick
> 2. Windows XP or later
> 3. Install [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)
> 4. Downlaod a [Ubuntu ISO file](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
> 5. Use Rufus to wipe the drive and place the ISO onto the USB
> 6. Press OK/Yes to the two warning boxes that pop up
> 7. You now have a bootable Ubuntu Live USB stick

Reboot your computer, and boot into the bootable usb stick. Then you will be guided through the installation instructions of Ubuntu, where you can select the options you want (wipe Windows or install alongside Windows).

You can also follow [these](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) installation instructions.

Comment: Just remember to hold "F12" on a Lenovo laptop once it reaches the boot screen, this will give you the option of where to boot the OS from. (your USB stick)

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as above. Personally, whenever I do a new setup, I boot into a Windows OS. Then, I make the Ubuntu live USB using PowerISO or Rufus. Then, I boot into it, and run the installer. The installer has an option in there to remove everything and install Ubuntu. Choose this option to wipe the machine and install Ubuntu standalone.

If you want to dual boot after that, you have to shrink the size of the disk, and choose "something else" when you're installing the other Linux OS. Manually create the ext4 and swap.